# Apply Radial gradient effect in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

How to apply radial gradient effect to a selected listbox item?

e.g. Please review left side listbox:
[image]

I have created the `RadialGradientBrush` as follows:

```
<RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.22,0.372">
   <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
              <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.1" CenterY="0.55" ScaleX="4" ScaleY="2"/>
              <TranslateTransform X="0.45" Y="0.05"/>
        </TransformGroup>
   </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
   <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
   <GradientStop Color="#FFE8E8E8"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Initially misread the question, updated answer.

One way to achieve the result you're after would be to redefine the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` for your `ListBox`, using the `Brush` you described. This `Brush` would then be used for highlighting, e.g:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Style.Resources>
            <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" GradientOrigin="0.22,0.372">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.1" CenterY="0.55" ScaleX="4" ScaleY="2"/>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0.45" Y="0.05"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE8E8E8"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to set the background to only `selected item` in the listbox and not the whole listbox

Comment: The use some `Triggers` The Brush above along with the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem`